# jQuery/Ajax fadeIn() after images/etc have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a script that loads pages via ajax for users with custom URLs. For example, a profile is typically located at http://example.com/users/Dan but if a user has a custom URL, say, http://example.com/DansCustomURL, then I need to fetch their desired target URL (in this case the user's profile /users/Dan).

Once the HMTL has been fetched and loaded into the `data` parameter, the content appears immediately, but the CSS styling and some images etc. take a bit longer causing the page to look broken until they are loaded.

Is there anyway to detect when all the elements located in the `data` variable have been loaded?

My HTML and inline Javascript/jQuery/Ajax is below.

```
<omni>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var rewritePath = '/users/Dan';
        $.get(rewritePath, function(data,status) {
            $('.hidden-element').append(data).onDataElementsLoad(function() {
                $(this).fadeIn();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="hidden-element"></div>
</omni>
```

Of course `.onDataElementsLoad()` is not a real method, but this is what I'm looking to do.

I'm familiar with the `waitForImages` plugin, but I was hoping to not need another dependency for this (seemingly) simple task.

An example can be seen at https://merkd.com/url.php?url=dan

I was going to post a fiddle, but it wouldn't allow me to use an external link in that way.

(A preloader will be added in the future, but the issue of preloading for the images in `data` would still exist.)

I tried the `.done()` method as instructed by another user in an answer below, but it does not prevent the page from appearing broken before styling/images are loaded.

This is the code I'm using now, and as you can see, the example still page still has a delay in styling/loading elements after the content itself appears.

```
        var rewritePath = '/u/dan';
        $.get(rewritePath).done(function(data) {
            console.log('loaded');
            $('omni').after(data).remove();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
$.get( "test.cgi", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } )
 .done(function( data ) {
   alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
 });
```

.done is callback for success load content from ajax in $.get function.

Comment: I updated my question with code that I used mimicking your approach, but it still does not prevent the delayed styling of some elements, as I described in my updated question. Any idea why?

Comment: Now is a question about how you parse data from your request. If you worried about delay loading page, you can just put loading animation before loaded stuff.

Answer (score 0):

No need for ajax. You can do something like this

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'http://somedomain.com/image.jpg')
    .on('load', function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            alert('broken image!');
        } else {
            $("#something").append(img).fadeIn(50);
        }
    });
```